# Can't append html code into existing element, got [object HTMLElement], not a real code

Tags: c#, jquery, json

Using .net core I've received some JSON data and using it I generate some table. In this table I should add some checkbox, but appending it to td doesn't work for me.
Code sample #1:

```
var table = $('#tab1 tbody');
$.each(response.nodes, function (index, value) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.setAttribute("class", "entireRow");

    var td1 = document.createElement("td");
    td1.setAttribute("class", "toGenerate");
    if (!value.nodeName || (value.nodeName.length > 0 && !value.hasChilds)) {
        td1.append($("<div class='checkbox'><label><input name='toRegen' id='td-gen-chbx-" + value.index + "' type='checkbox' class='td-gen-chbx'></label></div>"));
        }
        else {
            td1.append($.parseHTML("<center> - </center>"));
        }

    tr.appendChild(td1);
    table.append(tr);
});
```

I've tried 3 options:

```
td1.append($.parseHTML(...));
td1.append($(...));
td1.append("code directly");
```

Expected result: checkbox appended if there some value, - appended if not.

Actual results:

• td1.append(".."); - shows code as text as in this screen:
[image: code as text]

• td1.append($.parseHTML("")); - shows [object HTMLElement] instead of checkbox

•  td1.append($("")); - shows [object Object] as in this screen:
[image: code as object]

Comment: try to set inner html of the td instead of td.append

Comment: @AbMishra oh... it works :)) thanks a lot!!!